# Why is it important to test earth-to-live resistance at high voltage?

Tags: resistance, grounding

I recently had a water leak near an electrical junction box, causing an earth-to-live fault.

With the circuit completely disconnected from the breaker and all appliances unplugged, I could test with a cheap multimeter that the earth-to-live resistance was only 20kΩ.

However, electricians have told me that my multimeter test was meaningless, and what matters is the resistance using professional equipment (such as made by Megger) that would test the resistance at much higher voltages.

What is the technical reason for testing at high voltage, and is the cheap multimeter useful to diagnose anything at all?

Comment: You want to measure effects such as bad insulation don't you; these may not be detected with an ohm meter.

Comment: @Andyaka thanks. Do you happen to know what an acceptable minimum resistance would be in the UK between live and earth, when tested at high voltage?

Comment: Your meter is useful for doing the things it was designed to do. High voltage insulation testing is not one of those things. But it could, for instance, test for continuity and loop resistance of a ring main or check a fuse, filament lamp or battery.

Comment: Just for info, a "Megger" can inject 3kV or more into the wiring.  It puts this across the circuit, then measures the (hopefully tiny) amount of current that flows.  From the voltage and current, it calculates a "leakage" resistance, ranging into the billions of Ohms.  Only a Megger can measure these very high values of resistance - a multimeter, because it is using a much lower voltage, usually tops-out at 20M Ohms.

Comment: You are testing the quality of the insulation, which is easier to do at high voltage, since there is a difference between 1MΩ and 10MΩ.  Hard to do with a DMM.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat I think you're saying that the DMM would have low accuracy in the 1MΩ-10MΩ range. For that to matter, the minimum acceptable resistance would also need to be approximately in that range too, right? If earth-live resistance needs to be at least 100MΩ, wouldn't a DMM reading of 1MΩ definitely imply a fault, even if the real value is closer to 10MΩ? I'm not sure what an acceptable resistance lower limit should be.

Comment: Normal maintenance uses Meggers to see if insulation is degrading.  This could be from dirt tracking on conductive surfaces, as in, schedule a cleaning.  As long as insulation is >10MΩ consistenly, then there is no problem.  But if it starts to decrease and cleaning does not have an effect, then it is an indication that the insulation is starting to fail, which means the device, wire, etc is starting to fail.  Disconnect everything and megger individually.  You can't get there with just a DMM.

Comment: [“A Stitch In Time” The Complete Guide to Electrical Insulation Testing](https://www.instrumart.com/assets/Megger-Guide-to-Insulation-Testing.pdf)

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat that's an incredible resource, thanks!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your common voltmeter is fine for FAIL testing. 20k = you have a problem.

However it is not OK for PASS testing.  But you don't need it in North American residential wiring, at the least.  Other countries like the UK require it because of unique conditions there. (difficulty of placing wires in well-protected areas due to differing construction, especially in pre-1900 homes).

Insulation failure is often dependent on voltage.  That is, almost all insulation works like a Voltage Breakover device (VBO) - it insulates to a certain voltage, and then, it conducts.

Thus, to get an "all clear" indication *with an ohmmeter* you need one with a high test voltage of 150-250% of operating voltage (mindful of RMS). That's a megger.

In North America, you don't need that in residential AC power wiring.  Thorough repair, cleaning and inspection is good enough, because all connections occur in accessible junction boxes and interconnecting cables/wires are reasonably well protected. (an abundance of timber permits stud-wall construction; cables are run through centerline of studs).  Even so it can be useful in a few cases, such as underground direct burial wiring runs. One must be careful - meggers tend to fry electronics in the area under test.

Note that NM type "Romex" cable is not rated to be in wet locations. Water will wick up the paper packing, and will rot the conductor insulation, causing hot-earth or neutral-earth leakage which will trip GFCIs/RCDs.  The #1 cause of annoying ground fault trips in outdoor wiring is improper use of NM.

Comment: Thanks, you are the only person to have mentioned that a Megger is not typically used for residential AC wiring. Yes, I do have a 30mA RCD (in a UK house), and it was the RCD tripping that indicated that there was a problem in the first place (before I was aware of the water leak). It's reassuring to know that I can just see if the RCD trips or not, and that is good enough a test to see if things have dried out.

Comment: Your comments on meggers in residential certainly don't apply worldwide. I know of several EU countries where a megger test is a mandatory part of the inspection required before bringing new residential wiring into service.

Comment: @TooTea might it be the case that a Megger is used only on first installation in some countries, but is not considered necessary/appropriate for diagnosing faults years or decades after installation?

Comment: @AndrewParks Oh yes, that is likely the case. If that was what Harper meant, then I just misunderstood.

Comment: Insulation testers absolutely are considered appropriate in the UK for work on existing installations, both for certifying work and for fault finding.

Comment: @AndrewParks Thanks for the reminder. Yes, I should not have taken such a North American view. Edited.

Comment: @TooTea good point, and corrected.

Comment: @PeterGreen Yes, corrected.

Answer (score 11):

If your meter at 2V shows a problem, so will a professional meter with higher voltage.

A professional meter will just be able to find existing problems and future problems by making sure the insulation has no issues at rated voltages.

Your cheap meter has two problems, it can't see if there are problems at higher voltages in the insulation, and it is not a professional meter that has specifications and qualifications, maybe even calibration and testing abilities so it is known, verified, allowed, and guaranteed to be able to find hazardous things in the electrical system.

So it is not entirely meaningless, but to a professional electrician, it is rather useless if better measurements with better specs are required before an installation can be said to pass the requirements.

As an example, mains is about 110V or 230V depending on where you live. 230V rms has peak voltage of 325V, and in a 230V three-phase system there is 400VAC between live wires - that's a peak voltage of 566V. In many cases devices are safety tested to pass 1000V insulation test without leakage or breakdown with a spark. During lightning storms there can be high voltage surges.

Answer (score 7):

The higher voltage will jump any micro-gaps in the insulaton. Your multimeter is testing at about 2 V and won't have the potential to do that.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. However, does your answer imply that my multimeter would show false negatives (i.e. not indicate a fault when there is one), but that it would not show false positives (because if the resistance is low even at 2V, then that is definitely a problem that would also show up at higher voltages?)

Comment: Your understanding sounds correct.

Answer (score 4):

As well as finding micro-gaps, as identified by Transistor, it is also possible for failing insulation to be non-ohmic, i.e. have a non-linear relationship between leakage current and applied voltage. So insulation can show adequately high resistance when tested at a few volts but the resistance can fall when tested at the full mains voltage.

To ensure a safety margin it's usual to test with one of 250, 500 or 1,000 V DC, chosen to be about twice the AC operating voltage. (DC is used so that any capacitors in the equipment under test don't conduct current.) Professional insulation testing meters, such as Meggers, will be able to generate the voltages relevant to the region they are used in.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for using insulation testers is that failing insulation has a tendency to behave non-linearly. Most materials will behave in a relatively linear manner until they reach some breakdown voltage, then the effective resistance will decrease massively.

If a multimeter says the insulation is bad, then it's bad. However if your multimeter says it's good, that doesn't necessarily mean it is good. It is very possible to have insulation that gives an "off-scale" reading on a multimeter but conducts unacceptable amounts of electricity at mains voltages. Sometimes even enough to trip a RCD.

Practices clearly vary around the world, here in the UK the norm is for professional electricians to perform insulation tests. Both as part of the standard tests when issuing certificates for a new or modified installation, as part of a fault finding process and when performing a condition report on an existing installation. Insulation tests are also commonly performed as part of the in-service testing of electrical equipment.

Ideally, before performing an insulation test on an installation, or part thereof any equipment likely to be damaged by testing or likely to influence the test results should be disconnected. Insulation tests can then be performed between all combinations of conductors.

If equipment is being tested, an installation is being tested with equipment still connected or there is uncertainty about whether all equipment has been disconnected an alternative test method is used. Live and neutral are connected together and then a test is performed between the combined live and neutral conductors and earth. In some cases (for example if surge protection equipment is connected) the test voltage may be reduced to 250V.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I'm in the UK, and I have home emergency insurance from a very well known British brand. When the RCD started tripping (prior to the water leak being discovered), the emergency electrician was totally uninterested in doing fault finding. He insisted his job was only to make the electrics safe and disconnect the failing circuit. He just said the wiring is aluminium and old, and the whole house needed to be rewired. Only later we discovered the cause was water. Do you happen to know if it's normal in the UK for emergency electricians to refuse to find any faults?

Comment: I don't know what the norm is for home emergency services, but it doesn't surprise me that they do the bare minimum to make the house habitable again.  As for wiring materials, it's not impossible that you really do have aluminium, but it's equally likely that you have tinned copper and the electrician misidentified it.

Comment: I checked with two different emergency electricians about the aluminium wiring, and they said for sure it was aluminium based on the color. They said tinned copper would be slightly yellowy-silver. I might not have scratched hard enough, but I was unable to use a knife to scratch off any layer of tin to reveal copper. It was hard to tell, though, because a complicating factor is that the brass socket screws were leaving copper-coloured residue on the wires.